# Jms - Failed to call on message

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, hornetq

I am using Hornetq as the JMS mode of communication. Even after the message listener is set properly, there are some scenarios in which I get "Failed to call on message"(Message Listener). This doesn't happen always but at-times. Due to this certain messages that are critical for a system is lost at times. Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: Add you code please.

Comment: I might be sued for that probably. May be adding to it. It is a project wherein multiple (10/20) synchronous message gets pumped across the hornetq server. Each and every message constructs a connection.